# Getting vc-diff to use ediff in Emacs 23.2

Tags: version-control, emacs, diff

Had this working well in Emacs 23.1.x but it appears to have broke in the move to Emacs 23.2

I want to use ediff when comparing working copy of a file with SVN HEAD.

Normally I press *C-x v =* and ediff runs because of the following configuration in my .emacs

```
;; Use ediff and not diff 
(setq diff-command "ediff")
```

But, alas I still get the normal vc-diff buffer appearing and no ediff session...

Has anyone else encountered this and know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out I could just rebind <kbd>C-x v =</kbd> to the following:

```
(defun ediff-current-buffer-revision () 
  "Run Ediff to diff current buffer's file against VC depot. 
Uses `vc.el' or `rcs.el' depending on `ediff-version-control-package'." 
  (interactive) 
  (let ((file (or (buffer-file-name) 
          (error "Current buffer is not visiting a file")))) 
(if (and (buffer-modified-p) 
     (y-or-n-p (message "Buffer %s is modified. Save buffer? " 
                (buffer-name)))) 
    (save-buffer (current-buffer))) 
(ediff-load-version-control) 
(funcall 
 (intern (format "ediff-%S-internal" ediff-version-control-package)) 
 "" "" nil)))
```

This approach means you avoid having to specify the versions to compare as it defaults to comparing HEAD and the current file state.

Source: http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about152826.html

Comment: I needed to load the ediff packet first before this code would work. `(require 'ediff)`

Answer (score 8):

Am a bit skeptical that the above setting did what you say it did.

That said, this will bind '=' to use `'ediff-revision`:

```
(eval-after-load "vc-hooks"
         '(define-key vc-prefix-map "=" 'ediff-revision))
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the command `vc-ediff` to skip entering the file names: just compare the current modified copy with the base version (HEAD).

```
(eval-after-load "vc-hooks"
         '(define-key vc-prefix-map "=" 'vc-ediff))
```

Then `C-x v =` will bring up the Ediff session.

Comment: You're duplicating @trey's answer

Comment: @DavorCubranic `vc-ediff` and `ediff-revision` are different commands.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman is correct and this is a useful answer, my bad. On the other hand, it is also so similar to Trey's that it could have also been done as a comment there.