# Diff in Emacs between version of file in working dir and previous commit in git repo

Tags: git, emacs, diff

I have a git repository. I edit a file from the repository in Emacs and I want to use ediff in Emacs to see the differences between the text in the buffer visiting the file and a previous commit of the same file (by default the last commit). Is this possible / easy to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sounds like `M-x ediff-revision` is what you want. It allows you to refer to revisions using the normal syntax you use for your RCS, such as git.

I see that there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712834/getting-vc-diff-to-use-ediff-in-emacs-23-2)

Answer (score 13):

Git is well [supported](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Git). You should be able to use the normal [vc](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VersionControl) package "C-x v = vc-diff".

Comment: This indeed works. I was also wondering if I could see the differences in a clearer way, for example, show the two versions side-by-side the way ediff shows differences.

Comment: With `ediff-revision` I use pipe `|` character to switch to side-by-side view.